# php while loop addtitional condition not behaving as expected

Tags: php, loops, while-loop, multiple-conditions

I have this piece of code:

```
        $i=0;
        while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
*(line 133)*    if (array_search("SUCCESS", $row) != false) {
                echo "<tr class='success'>";
            }
            elseif (array_search("ERROR", $row) != false) {
                echo "<tr class='danger'>";
            }
            else {
                echo "<tr>";
            }
                foreach ($row as $rowData) {
                    if ($rowData == "SUCCESS") {
                        echo "<td><span class='mdi-navigation-check'></span></td>";
                    }
                    elseif ($rowData == "ERROR") {
                        echo "<td><span class='mdi-navigation-close'></span></td>";
                    }
                    else {
                        if (gettype($rowData) == "object") {
                            echo "<td>" . $rowData->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "</td>";
                        } else {
                            echo "<td>" . $rowData . "</td>";
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (isset($row["cMsgID"])) {
                    echo "<td><a href='#' onclick='window.open(\"/monitor/templates/history.php?cMsgID=" . $row["cMsgID"] . "\", \"history\", \"status=1, toolbar=1 width=800px, height=400px\")'>History</a></td>";
                }
            echo "</tr>";
            $i++;
        }
```

But when I add a second condition to the while loop the `$row` variable becomes a boolean `true`:

```
$i
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) && $i < 10){
*same code as above*}
```

First php error message: **Warning: array_search() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given in C:\wamp32bit\www\monitor\templates\mainContent.php on line 133**

I have searched for this problem but all of them were related to wrong syntax or the conditions excluding each other.

Why does this happen?

Comment: You define $i to be 0, so 0 is smaller than 10. This is really true!  BTW you should post the whole code within the loop.

Comment: @bub But why does this overwrite the `$row` variable? It should write the array to `$row` and then see if `$i` is also smaller than 10, right?

Comment: Please post the whole loop code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here is just syntax, that way you are assigning always a boolean value to the $row.

`$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) && $i < 10`

The right way to do this is

`($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) && $i < 10`

In the last case you can put an if statment inside the loop, like this:

`$i=0
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
    if ($i < 10) {
        *do something*
    } else {
        break;
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try this?

`while($i < 10){
     while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
          your code here;
     }
}`

Comment: This will the inner loop multiple times which is not what I want, I want multiple conditions in one loop

Answer (score 0):

Another way you could do it would be :

```
$i=0;    
while (true == ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) && $i < 10) {
    *code*
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that sqlsrv_fetch_array returns an array and not a boolean

Comment: Yes, which it assigns to the $row variable.  If there are no more rows to fetch, the statement would equate to false.  Try it, it should work for you.